# Poor quality and lack of sharpness with flutter_svg package

Tags: flutter

I am working on a Flutter project and facing an issue with the quality and sharpness of SVG icons when using the [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package. Here is my code for displaying an SVG icon:

```
SvgPicture.asset(
 "assets/icons/setting_outline.svg",
  colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(
  Colors.white,
  BlendMode.srcIn,
  ),
 width: 18,
 height: 18,
)
```

The problem is that the icon does not appear sharp and has poor quality. However, when I use the [Iconsax](https://pub.dev/packages/iconsax) like this:

```
Icon(Iconsax.setting_2, size: 18)
```

The icon looks much sharper and of higher quality. Interestingly, when I increase the size of SvgPicture.asset to 50, the icon's quality improves.

I would like to know why this quality issue occurs with flutter_svg at smaller sizes and how I can achieve better quality and sharpness for smaller SVG icons using the flutter_svg package.

This is my svg icon file using: [SVG File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SF1-7D_N9UPVXGfrCd16cIQIyi8hy5tM/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: try fit: BoxFit.contain , This can help improve the clarity of small icons.